# Open a hidden div in a lightbox with Mootools in Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, mootools, joomla1.5

I am using Joomla 1.5.22 with Mootools 1.1. I have a module with a form contained in a hidden div that I want to open in Joomla's built in modal box. The problem I have is that when I click the link the form opens in the modal box, but it also opens the div in the module on the page.

HTML:

```
<div id="moduleBox">
    <div id="clickMeButton"><a id="formClick" class="modal" href="#hiddenForm">Click me</a></div>
    <div id="hiddenForm">
     form code goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  $('formClick').addEvent('click', function(){
    $('hiddenForm').setStyle('display','block');
  });
});
```

So how do I get the form to only show up in the modal box?

You can see what I am talking about here - http://www.internextion.com/

It's the Call Back Module. I already added the     handler: 'adopt' as suggested below, now the result is a little different. The target div still shows up below the link, but now the modal window contains the link rather than the target.

Comment: I haven't added much CSS other than hiding the form with #hiddenform{display:none;}

Comment: please add little bit more explanation. If possible add screen shots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got it to work with a combination of the other answers given. First, I removed the javascript click event to make the form appear, that solved the issue of the form showing up below the link. Next, I added new CSS for the hiddenForm ID within the modal box and set that to display:block. It appears that the default handler behavior (in Joomla at least) is to adopt the content since I have removed the `handler: 'adopt'` and it is still adopting the content.

I knew it was something simple, thanks for the help!

BTW - the link is still live, you can see the correct behavior on the demo site. Now all I need to do is add some fancy AJAX form submission and it will be ready for prime time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this uses Harald's SqueezeBox - in which case, you are looking at the following scenarios:

- find the target div and CLONE it to insert into the modal box.
- find the target div and ADOPT it into the modal box.

you are seeing the first (default) case. to achieve the second effect, add:

`handler: 'adopt'`

to the instantiation options. more here: http://digitarald.de/project/squeezebox/1-1/showcase/get-elements/

Comment: No we are getting close. If I leave handler: 'adopt' out, you can see both divs appear. One below the link, one in the modal box. If I add it, instead of the target div, it clones the link that you click and still displays the form below the link. Take a look - http://www.internextion.com/ it's the Call Back Module.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1:

If you look at the html code (in firebug) for the overlay div you will see that it makes a "copy" of html and places inside the overlay container with `id="sbox-content"`. In theory if you add a CSS like below +/-, it will hide the link and display everything else. This might be the simplest and easiest solution.

```
div#sbox-content > a#formClick{
   display: none;
}
```

### Option 2:

If option 1 does not work for some reason, you can try playing with CSS and hide the link when the Modal box opens and then making it visible when it closes.

Modify the JS to add a class instead of modifying the style.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  $('formClick').addEvent('click', function(){
    $('formClick').addClass('hidden');
    $('hiddenForm').setStyle('display','block'); 
  });
});
```

Load additional CSS that will make the link invisible

```
div#clickMeButton.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Then you will have to overload closing event and make the link visible...

Comment: This doesn't work because the modal box is displaying the incorrect div when I add handler: 'adopt' to the link parameters. If I remove that code, the form shows up in the box like it is supposed to, but the form also shows up under the link. When I add your code, the form shows up under the box and the modal box is now empty because it never loads the form div in there like it is supposed to.

Comment: The contents of the modal box is now: <a id="formClick" href="#hiddenForm" class="modal formbutton" rel="{size:{x:175,y:175},handler: 'adopt'}">Click and Google will connect you for free.</a>, it should be <div id="hiddenForm">...</div>